# How to delete/discard certain words from strings in a text file?

Tags: string, matlab, substring, text-processing

I have a text file with these contents:

```
GULBERG (source)
MODEL TOWN (destination)
```

I want to extract **GULBERG** and  **MODEL TOWN** (or any other names that appear here) and discard ***(source)*** and ***(destination)*** from the file using Matlab. Further, I'm saving these names to variables `STRING{1}`,`STRING{2}` for later use.

But the problem i'm facing is that my code extracts only "GULBERG" and "MODEL" from the file *and not the second word i.e "TOWN"*.

My output so far:

```
GULBERG
MODEL
```

*How can i fix this so that i get the word TOWN as well in the output??*

Here's my code:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');

thisline = fgets(fid);
a=char(40); %character code for paranthesis (
b=char(41); %character code for paranthesis )
STRING=cell(2,1);
ii=1;

while ischar(thisline)
  STRING{ii}=sscanf(thisline,['%s' a b 'source' 'destination']);
  ii=ii+1;
  thisline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);

% STRING{1} contains first name 
% STRING{2} contains second name
```

Comment: Looks like `matlab` to me, still needs confirmation.

Comment: don't `sscanf()`, it's horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the identifiers - `(source)` and `(destination)` always appear at the end of the lines after the town names that are to be detected, see if this works for you -

```
%%// input_filepath and output_filepath are filepaths 
%%// of input and output text files

str1 = importdata(input_filepath)

split1 = regexp(str1,'\s','Split')

%%// Store row numbers that do not have (source) or (destination) as a string
ind1 = ~cellfun(@isempty,(regexp(str1,'(source)'))) | ...
    ~cellfun(@isempty,(regexp(str1,'(destination)')));

str1 = strrep(str1,' (source)','')
str1 = strrep(str1,' (destination)','')

STRING = str1(ind1,:)

%%// Save as a text file
fid = fopen(output_filepath,'w');
for k = 1:size(STRING,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',STRING{k,:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was waiting for an answer, i did more digging myself and found the solution to my problem. Looks like using `strrep()` to replace the unwanted words with `''` solved my problem.
I'm sharing this so anyone with a similar problem might find this helpful!

Here's what I did:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
thisline = fgets(fid);
a=char(40);
b=char(41);
STRING=cell(2,1);
index=1;
while ischar(thisline)
STRING{index} = strrep(thisline,'(source)','');
 index=index+1;
    thisline = fgets(fid);
end
STRING{2} = strrep(STRING{2},'(destination)','');
fclose(fid);
```